# Same Tab content over three different pages, how to active the coreesponding tabs according to the page id wordpress

Tags: tabs, nav

> Same Tab content over three different pages, how to active the
>   coreesponding tabs according to the page id wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var tar=jQuery(location).attr('href');
    if(tar=="pageid1")
    {

        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(2) a").tab('show');
        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(2) a").addClass('active');

    }
    if(tar=="pageid2")
    {

        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(0) a").tab('show');
        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(0) a").addClass('active');

    }
    if(tar=="pageid3")
    {

        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(1) a").tab('show');
        jQuery("#tabMenu li:eq(1) a").addClass('active');

    }


      });



</script>
```